# Hide action column items in ext js

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to hide action column items on condition, Please look below code.

```
{
 xtype: 'actioncolumn',
 flex: 1,
 sortable: false,
 menuDisabled: true,
 align: 'center',
 items: [{

     icon: (fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/edit2.png' : '',
     tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_EDIT_'),
     scope: this,

     handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {

         //var data = Vehiclestore.data.items[rowIndex].data;
         var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
         console.log(rec);
         if (fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) {
             this.fireEvent("ShowVehicleDetails", rec);
         }
     }
 }, {
     xtype: 'spacer'
 }, {
     icon: (Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('issuperadmin') == 1 ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png' : ''),
     //(fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Deletemanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'D') != null) ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png' : '',  // Use a URL in the icon config  

     tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_DELETE_'),
     handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
         var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
         if (fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Deletemanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'D') != null) {
             Ext.Msg.show({
                 title: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_REMOVETITLE_'),
                 msg: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_REMOVEMSG_'),
                 buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                 icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                 callback: function(button) {
                     if (button == fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_YESBTN_')) {
                         me.removeVehicle(rec);
                     }
                 }
             });
         }
     }
 }]
}
```

In above code, Action column contain 3 Items, **Edit, space (i.e.  { xtype: 'spacer' }),** and **Delete** Icons. I want to hide Delete Icon on condition. Means delete option shown only when admin user login. 
please look design for this, you can get better idea about problem

[image]

Using this code bellow I am able to hide Delete icon but tooltip and click event still fire on click on hidden icon location.

```
icon: (Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('issuperadmin') == 1 ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png' : ''),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think hiding or disabling the icon is the solution here. If the user is not admin why bother with adding the icon at all. I would `buildActionColumnItems` method that will return the items for the action column based on current user's role.

The action column config:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    flex: 1,
    sortable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    align: 'center',
    items: this.buildActionColumnItems()
}
```

The `buildActionColumnItems` method implementation:

```
buildActionColumnItems: function () {
    //set the implicit items
    var columnItems = [{
        icon: (fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/edit2.png' : '',
        tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_EDIT_'),
        ...
    }];

    //add aditional items if the user is super admin
    if (Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('issuperadmin') == 1) {
        columnItems.push({
            xtype: 'spacer'
        });
        columnItems.push({
            icon: FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png',
            tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_DELETE_'),
            ...
        });
    }

    return columnItems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding use  isDisabled() method.

To work the method has to be in the actioncolumn itself.

```
    isDisabled: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, items, record) {
        if (condition) {
             return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20pr

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want hide and hideMode.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-hidden
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-hideMode

note: untested

```js
{
     xtype: 'actioncolumn',
     flex: 1,
     sortable: false,
     menuDisabled: true,
     align: 'center',
     items: [{

     // add the type of rendering method you want
     hideMode: 'display',

     // do permissions check here
     hide: fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) ? true : false,

     icon:(fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/edit2.png' : '',
     tooltip: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_VEHICLE_VEHICLELIST_EDIT_'),
     scope: this,
     handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
       //var data = Vehiclestore.data.items[rowIndex].data;
       var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
       console.log(rec);
       if (fleet.rolerightscreate.modulerights('Editmanagevehicle', 'Manage Vehicle', 'E') != null) {
         this.fireEvent("ShowVehicleDetails", rec);
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getClass` method in same object

```
handler: function(grid, rowindex, cellIndex, a, e, record, tr) {
    if (condition)
       {
        //some logic
       }
    },
getTip: function(v, meta, rec) {
     if (condition) {
         return '';
     } else {
         return 'ToolTip';
     }
    }
getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {
   if (condition) {
                return '';
        } else {
                return 'co-delete-ico';
        }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I used this code :--> icon: (Ext.getStore('userStore').first().get('issuperadmin') == 1 ? FLEET_SERVER_URL + 'images/del.png' : ''),

but this only get hide 'delete' icon, When I gose on that location of icon I see tooltip and when I click there delete window popups.

Comment: I have updated the answer, in handle function also you have to check your condition then it will not open delete popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can change css for disabled item for example in sass file

```
.grid-custom {
    .x-action-col-cell .x-item-disabled {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}


isActionDisabled: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, record) {
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add css class

```
.grid-cell-action-col-item-hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and if you want hide you could add css to element like:

```
getClass: function(v, meta, record) {
   if(hideFn(record)){
        return 'grid-cell-action-col-item-hide';
   }
   return "";
}
```